# Operation not permitted when trying to open tmux

Tags: macos, tmux, apple-m1

When I try to initiate tmux session it gives me the following error.

```
error creating /private/tmp/tmux-501 (Operation not permitted)
```

I am using apple M1 (Big Sur version 11.5.2). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It was not just with tmux but I couldn't read/write on the `/tmp` folder even with sudo permission. This blocked me from using apps that require its use.

I couldn't find the actual reason behind it, I think it was locked by another program which terminated badly.
The only option I could have opted for at this point was to reboot my system.